# jQuery-select2 - Get values in the order they were selected

Tags: jquery, select, multi-select, jquery-select2

I'm developing a form with a number of multiselects. I use Select2 library for that.

```
 $(".chosen-select").select2({
            allow_single_deselect: true,
            width: "150px"
        });
......
<select id="ship2" class="chosen-select" data-placeholder="Select vessel">
<option></option>
<option value="value1">title1</option>
<option value="value2">title2</option>
</select>
```

The problem is that when I try to get selected values they are returned in the order they are specified in `<select>` element, not the order they have been selected:

```
var selectedDayPorts = $('#ship2');
var dayPorts = selectedDayPorts.select2("val");
```

Is there a way to get them in correct order?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I didn't find a way how to make select2 to store values in the correct order, so I ended up creating hidden input fields for each select2-field and update it accordingly as I add/remove new values

Comment: How come this option is selected even though no one can see the working answer...

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes this may be a help. After trying several methods I have came up with a workaround using the code i get with this link on user shashilo.
https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3106

But I had to do few arrangements as it didn't worked 100% on my case.
Here is my code.

```js
$(".select2").on("select2:select", function (evt) {
          var element = evt.params.data.element;
          var $element = $(element);

          if ($(this).find(":selected").length > 1) {
            var $second = $(this).find(":selected").eq(-1);
            $second.after($element);
          } else {
            $element.detach();
            $(this).prepend($element);
          }

          $(this).trigger("change");
        });
```

In the link he mentioned

```js
var $second = $(this).find(":selected").eq(-2);
```

But what worked for me was

```js
var $second = $(this).find(":selected").eq(-1);
```

And this worked well even with deselecting items too in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var dayPorts = selectedDayPorts.select2("data");
```

And get values:

```
alert(dayPorts[0]['id']);

alert(dayPorts[0]['text']);
```